# A maximal inequality for random variables with finite $L^{p}$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, random-variables, expectation

I would appreciate any help with the following question from Kosorok's *Introduction to Empirical Processes and Semiparametric Inference* (Q10.5.2):

> Show that for any $p>1$ and any real i.i.d. $X_{1},\ldots, X_{n}$ with
>   $E |X|^{p}<\infty$, we have \begin{align} E \max_{1\leq i\leq
>  n}\frac{|X_{i}|}{n^{1/p}} \to 0 \end{align} as $n\to \infty$.

**More Details:**
The hint provided for this question is to first show that for any $x>0$ we have:
\begin{align}
\limsup_{n\to \infty} P \left(\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\frac{|X_{i}|}{n^{1/p}} > x \right) \leq 1- \exp\left(- \frac{E|X|^{p}}{x^{p}} \right)
\end{align}
I thought that the following would be useful:
\begin{align}
\limsup_{n\to \infty}E \max_{1\leq i\leq n}\frac{|X_{i}|}{n^{1/p}} = \limsup_{n\to \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} P \left( \max_{1\leq i\leq n}\frac{|X_{i}|}{n^{1/p}} > x \right) dx
\end{align}
but honestly I cant make much progress.